# Python-Twilio is not sending sms with test credential.

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest, twilio

I have created trial account on twilio, and installed twilio using

```
pip install twilio
```

on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

below is my python code to send the sms

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

account_sid = "MY TEST ACCOUNT SID"
auth_token  = "MY TEST ACCOUNT TOKEN"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
print "running!!"

sms = client.sms.messages.create(body="All in the game, yo",
    to="+91MYNUMBER",
    from_="+1MY_TWILIO_NUMBER")
print sms.sid
print sms.status
```

While running this python file I am getting below log error from twilio.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/software/ws/extra/scripts/test.py", line 40, in 
    from_="+1MY_TWILIO_NUMBER")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/sms_messages.py", line 167, in create
    return self.create_instance(kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 365, in create_instance
    data=transform_params(body))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 200, in request
    resp = make_twilio_request(method, uri, auth=self.auth, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 164, in make_twilio_request
    uri=resp.url, msg=message, code=code)
twilio.rest.exceptions.TwilioRestException: HTTP 400 error: The From phone number +1MY_TWILIO_NUMBER is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.

I have checked my number has Capabilities for Voice, SMS & MMS.

I have checked this error on [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21606). then i tried with **+15005550006** number, It is running but the i never receive the sms on my cell phone.the message went in queue which never processes.

```
runnnign!!
SM3f51b1c3e5ad43d38bd548cfada14175
queued
```

What I am missing? why I am not getting the sms?

Comment: Are you using a VOIP #?

Comment: No right now I am just using sms.

Comment: Nexmo, where I work, has an SMS API that allows you to send SMS' to over 200 countries/territories with a simple HTTP call. You are allowed to whitelist up to 10 numbers to test the API out with and can top up your account once you have fully tested out our platform. You can try it out here: https://dashboard.nexmo.com/sign-up

Just for reference here is a link to the SMS API docs: https://docs.nexmo.com/api-ref/sms-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Test account credentials don't actually send SMS messages, they are test endpoints that let you know your HTTP calls are working as expected. That's why you have to use a specific number.

To test with the number you bought on your account you will need to use your real account credentials. Your Twilio trial account does come with some free credit to test these messages out before you need to upgrade, so I recommend changing to use those real credentials and the number you bought and you should start to see SMS messages coming through to your phone.

As a side note, the call to `client.sms.messages.create` actually uses a deprecated API. You can update that to `client.messages.create` and it will use the more modern [Messages endpoint](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages). (Side point on that though, the test credentials won't work at all with that endpoint, I still recommend using your real credentials and trial credit to test.)

Comment: ok, So first i need to buy a number from https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/search/buy/results. then add credits in my account, after that i can send the sms using the python api right?

Comment: I can't buy Indian Number there!

Comment: We do not have numbers in India right now. However you could buy a number from elsewhere and use it to send SMS messages to Indian numbers. To test this, you don't need to add credits to your account, there is free trial credit that you can use.

Comment: after buying number I will get free trial credit right? and using i can test the api, isn't i?

Comment: @philnash I'm glad you wrote this answer here, and I wish Twilio docs made this more obvious.  I wasted at least an hour just now trying to figure out why my test SMS messages weren't coming to my phone.

Comment: Hey @Ryan , I hear your comment. I'll see what I can do about getting test account credentials better documented for what they do and what they don't do. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Actually you cannot send message to unverified number until you purchase, but you can still send messages to  your registered and verified number.make sure your all numbers are correct, because i face this problem too.

Comment: Hey Kharek, you can send to verified numbers while your account is still in trial mode. However you definitely won't be able to send messages using the Test Credentials. To really send a message you need to use your live credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I used PHP to send the SMS from a trial account to a verified Indian number from a US number bought from Twilio. Didnt receive any message, though I can see the Sent status on the dashboard as well as on callbacks.
Have opened a ticket to check.